# Dictionary of dictionaries in python!

Tags: python

How do I create a dictionary in python whose values are also a dictionary?  Basically, my question is that I have this list of lists:

```
['http://a11y.in/a11ypi/idea/a11y_firesafety.html',
 ['lang:hi', 'lang:kn'],
 ['a11y_firesafety.html:div1', 'a11y_firesafety.html:div1'],
 ['hi', 'kn']
]
```

and I want to convert it to:

```
{'http://a11y.in/a11ypi/idea/a11y_firesafety.html':
  {'lang:hi':
     {'lang:kn':
        {'a11y_firesafety.html:div1':
           {'a11y_firesafety.html:div1': {'hi', 'kn'}}}}}}
```

Can someone suggest me a way to do it?  I tried using multidimensional dictionaries but they were of no use.  Please help!

Comment: It's not exactly clear from the one example how to build this dictionary.  Plus the last "dictionary" in your example `{'hi', 'kn'}` doesn't make sense syntactically.  Is that supposed to be a list?

Comment: `{'hi', 'kn'}` is not a dict, at most it's a set in more recent Python versions (those with set literals). Also, the problem description is more than vague and you practically provide *no* information about what you tried and how it failed.

Comment: @user567797: I agree with the other folks here -- your question could be a bit clearer, and I'm guessing `{'hi', 'kn'}` should read `{'hi' : 'kn'`}. Please consider `edit`ing the question to be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def forget_torpedoes(mylist):
    return reduce(lambda acc, x: {x : acc}, reversed(mylist))
```

This will work for a flat list as follows:

```
In [9]: forget_torpedoes( [5, 6, 7, 8] )
Out[9]: {5: {6: {7: 8}}}
```

I realize that doesn't answer (all) of your question, since you have nested lists. But then again, it should get you most of the way :)

Answer (score 2):

Building off of phooji's answer, you can use a function similar to itertools.chain to take care of the nested lists.

```
def forget_torpedoes(mylist):
    return reduce(lambda acc, x: {x : acc}, reversed(mylist))

def chain(iterable):
    for it in iterable:
        if isinstance(it, str):
            yield it
        else:
            for element in it:
                yield element

print forget_torpedoes(tuple(chain(nested_list)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
>>> l=['http://a11y.in/a11ypi/idea/a11y_firesafety.html',
...  ['lang:hi', 'lang:kn'],
...  ['a11y_firesafety.html:div1', 'a11y_firesafety.html:div1'],
...  ['hi', 'kn']
... ]
>>> d={}
>>> d[l[0]]=reduce(lambda val, key : {key : val}, reversed( sum(l[1:],[]) ))
>>> d
{'http://a11y.in/a11ypi/idea/a11y_firesafety.html': 
  {'lang:hi': 
     {'lang:kn': 
        {'a11y_firesafety.html:div1': 
           {'a11y_firesafety.html:div1': 
              {'hi': 'kn'}}}}}}
```

I'll leave it to you, fair reader, to explain it to your teacher...